# Order comments in admin by custom date

Tags: comments, order

I need to order the comments in the admin by a custom date field; named 'datum_van_uitvoering'.

At the front-end i did the trick with get_comments. But now i have to order the backend ass well and for what i know i have to do it with pre_get_comments.

So far, i have

```
add_filter('pre_get_comments','display_comments_ordered_by_metadate');
function display_comments_ordered_by_metadate($query){
global $pagenow;
if($query->is_admin) {
    $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'order' => 'DESC',  
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key' => 'datum_van_uitvoering',
        ]
    ];
}
}
```

But it's not yet working... Any advice here? 
Thanks

Comment: try replacing meta_value_num with meta_value_datetime or meta_value_date

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.

Comment: use add_action instead of add_filter

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and happy to share the code:

```
function cws_pre_get_comments( $comments ) {
  $comments->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'datum_van_uitvoering';
  $comments->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
  $comments->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
  $comments->meta_query->parse_query_vars( $comments->query_vars );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'cws_pre_get_comments' );
```

Comment: Note that this will modify comment queries all over the site!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, and yes this will be okay for this project. All comments must be ordered on a custom date field; not the standard comment date field.